# How to set setMaxMapTaskFailuresPercent in hadoop's new api?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Before, you could set max failures percent by using:

```
JobConf.setMaxMapTaskFailuresPercent(int)
```

but now, that's obsolete.

```
 job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.max.map.failures.percent", "100");
```

doesn't seem to work as well. What is the proper way of doing this in new hadoop api?

Answer (score 1):

On 1.0.2, list of supported options are given in http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.2/mapred-default.html, this you can pass through as a java system property through java -DoptionName=value when running the map reduce job.

Also to set them via the command line, see

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Job+Configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quickly find the correct names for the options for hadoop's new api, use this link: http://pydoop.sourceforge.net/docs/examples/intro.html#hadoop-0-21-0-notes .